# What immutable object works with List.contains?

Tags: java, list, immutability, contains

I want to create a list of coordinates and be able to check if this list contains a new coordinate.

I have tried implementing `Pair`, but using `List.contains()` with a `Pair` doesn't work, always returning false.

What other objects can I use that I will be able to check against `List.contains()`?

Comment: `List.contains` iterates the list items, looking for an element which matches using `equals(Object)`. You can use any class which correctly implements `equals(Object)` (it should have a corresponding implementation of `hashCode()` too, although that isn't used by `List.contains`). Please show your `Pair` class.

Comment: Pair itself still has to implement equals and hashcode btw. please show code reproducing the problem. Pair classes have always seemed worthless to me, i would make a coord class with x and y fields, or use 2-element arrays if i didn't want to make my own class.

Comment: Can you add the code which fails against `List.contains`?

Comment: You have to implement hashcode & equals to reliably work.

Comment: Also consider using a [HashSet](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because your implementation of `Pair` doesn't provide an overridden `equals` method. I was able to reproduce your issue using the following code:

```
//a plain POJO, in Pair.java
public class Pair<A, B> {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public Pair(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

//... Main.java

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<Integer, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Pair<Integer, String> one = new Pair<>(1, "hello");
        Pair<Integer, String> two = new Pair<>(1, "hello");
        list.add(one);
        System.out.println(list.contains(two));
    }
}
```

This prints out `false`, because `List.contains` uses object equality as a test (the default `equals` method in class `Object`). With the above code, for example, `one.equals(two)` evaluates to `false`, because they're not the same object. To fix this, you have to provide an `equals` method that looks at each field and compares them individually:

```
//in class Pair
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;
    return Objects.equals(a, pair.a) &&
            Objects.equals(b, pair.b);
}
```

You can delegate the somewhat tedious and error-prone task of writing this code to your IDE. I'm using Intellij, and it's only a matter of clicking `Code/Generate/equals() and hashcode()` . You don't need `hashcode()` for this particular case, but it's always a good idea to keep `equals()` and `hashcode()` together. Now, when `List.contains` tries to find an element that is equal to the one you provided, it will use this new and more appropriate method. If you run the `main` method again, you'll see it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution in relation to `Pair`, but for simplicity sake I was more interested in finding some data structure that worked with `List.contains()` "out of the box" per se.

Comment: @Recessive If by "data structure" you mean "classes", all will work with `List.contains`, just as long as they properly override `Object.equals()`. Try it out with `Integer` or `Date`, for example.

Comment: @Recessive As to a class having an `equals` method "out of the box", if it's a class you made yourself, then you have to specify a correctly implemented `equals()` method. If by "out of the box", you meant standard library classes, then you can look around at the classes used by Java, a lot of them override  the `equals()` method. See for example [the `Integer` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 0):

`List.contains` checks to see if two objects are equal using the `Object.equals` method. Therefore, it only works with objects that have an `Object.equals` method implemented. If you are writing your own `Pair` class, make sure you give it an `equals` method.

Answer (score -2):

I think your Pair contains the same value, but the object isn't the same. That's because it doesn't work. You could use a Map instead.

> **How you can use a map:**

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Hello", 0); // add key an value to map (Key: "Hello", Value: 0)
map.put("World", 1); // add key an value to map (Key: "World", Value: 1)

if (map.containsKey("World")) { // check if map contains key: "World"
  System.out.println(map.get("World")); // try return value by key: returns 1
  System.out.println(map.get("world")); // try return value by key: returns null
}

if (map.containsKey("Hello")) { // check if map contains key: "Hello"
  System.out.println(map.get("Hello")); // try return value by key: returns 0
  System.out.println(map.get("hello")); // try return value by key: returns null
}
```

Comment: As I was using pairs, I defined my list as `List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> checked = new ArrayList<>();`. This still failed when I did `checked.contains(new Pair(3,4));` even if the list clearly contained the `Pair` `(3,4)`.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question + `Others aren't recommended` why ?

Comment: This answer is not very helpful as it stands... perhaps explain how to use a Map?